# Make page fill the whole screen with no white space at all

Tags: html, css

My website is barkitv.com/barki/register-3 on some big screens there is white space and I do not want any white space i want it to fit the whole screen with out any white space, this is what I have tryed making the content 100% and making the footer go to the bottom with `position:absolute bottom:0;` but then there is still white space I have also tryed doing `min-height: 100%;` and doing `position:absolute bottom:0;` on the footer.

Thank You

Comment: i will try you guys answer

Comment: I'd like to point out that @kimchicode's answer only works because of your `div`'s `background-color`. Giving the background color to `body` instead would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've already got a sticky footer implemented. Just set a background-color on the body to match your content area:

```
body {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {min-height: 100%; background: black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

If you want to make it shorter to include the footer, simply decrease the number.

You might need to target a different element other than the body.

Like this:

```
.content {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set your `.content` div's height to be `100%`. But a better solution would be to set the `body`'s `background-color` to be that of the `.content`'s background color.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `html` and `body` tags are block elements and their height collapses to as small as they can be.

Make them occupy the entirety of the window with:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Secondly, the `body` tag has a `margin` of 8 pixels by default.

Remove this and make the elements it contains go right to the edges with:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Exemplified here: https://jsfiddle.net/3u8kqvxo/

Note that you don't actually want to use an all-encompassing wrapper like that, it's redundant because it's essentially just another `body`.

However, here's a nifty workaround to your footer issue that would give you a reason to use one: https://jsfiddle.net/3u8kqvxo/1/